# Create many to many on one table

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

Flask-SQLAlchemy gives an [example](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/models.html#many-to-many-relationships) of how to create a many to many relationship. It is done between two different tables.

Is it possible to create a many to many relationship on the same table? For example a sister can have many sisters, who would also have many sisters. I have tried:

```
girl_sister_map = db.Table('girl_sister_map',
                      db.Column('girl_id', 
                                db.Integer, 
                                db.ForeignKey('girl.id')),
                      db.Column('sister_id', 
                                db.Integer, 
                                db.ForeignKey('girl.id')))

class Girl(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    sisters = db.relationship('Girl',
                              secondary=girl_sister_map,
                              backref=db.backref('othersisters', lazy='dynamic'))
```

But when I try to add a sister to a girl I get:

> sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Girl.sisters - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables via secondary table 'girl_sister_map'.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference from the secondary table to each of the parent and child tables.

Is this possible? How should I be doing it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are trying to build what is called an [adjacency list](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html). That is you have a table with foreign key to itself.

In your specific case it is a [self referencial many to many relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many-relationship).

This is supported in SQLAlchemy as you will discover by following the previous link. The doc contains several examples.

Basically, you will need the `primaryjoin` and `secondaryjoin` arguments to establish how you would like to join the table. Straight from the doc:

```
Base = declarative_base()

node_to_node = Table("node_to_node", Base.metadata,
    Column("left_node_id", Integer, ForeignKey("node.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("right_node_id", Integer, ForeignKey("node.id"), primary_key=True)
)

class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    label = Column(String)
    right_nodes = relationship("Node",
                        secondary=node_to_node,
                        primaryjoin=id==node_to_node.c.left_node_id,
                        secondaryjoin=id==node_to_node.c.right_node_id,
                        backref="left_nodes"
    )
```