# SQL Alchemy many to many relationship with current table

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

For my application I need to create a link with points which is the same entity. Currently I do it this way.

```
association_table = db.Table('main_connectedpoints', Base.metadata,
                             db.Column('point_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('main_placepoint.id')),
                             db.Column('connected_point_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('main_placepoint.id')))


class PlacePoint(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'main_placepoint'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    lat = db.Column(db.Float())
    lon = db.Column(db.Float())
    address = db.Column(db.String())
    organizations = db.relationship('Organization', backref='main_placepoint',
                                    lazy='dynamic')
    related_points = db.relationship("PlacePoint",
                                     secondary=lambda: association_table)

    def __init__(self, dict_):
        self.name = dict_['name']
        self.lat = dict_['lat']
        self.lon = dict_['lon']
        self.address = dict_['address']

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Place %r" % self.address

    def as_dict(self):
        return {"name": self.name, "lat": self.lat, "lon": self.lon, "address": self.address}
```

But I have the following error: NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'main_connectedpoints.point_id' could not find table 'main_placepoint' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'

I suppose that it is because `PlacePoint` class is not instantiated. Any idea to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure association_table describe relation on the same table and the same field?

Comment: @AlexLisovoy yes, It should, I want connect points with each other.

Comment: @AlexLisovoy typically many to many relationship used to reference 2 different tables. I want create relationship between the same table. Is it possible?

Comment: sure, read [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many-relationship). This answer can be helpful [Create many to many on one table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252816/create-many-to-many-on-one-table)

Comment: Make sure that both the model `PlacePoint` and the table `association_table` are using the same `MetaData`. Most probably instead of `Base.metadata` you should really use `db.metadata`. Or remove the reference to `Base.metadata` alltogether, in which case the proper one would be used.